# Cisco Wireless Guest user management

Tags: wlc, cisco-ise

I am in bad situation where I was allowed to build wireless network for my company, I did so using WLC-2504 with 7 APs registered, but I was not aware of the limitations of generating random username and password with in WLC, I worked alot for this with cisco and other but could not get(cisco has option to generate 1 username/password for guest single point of time).

please help me get any additional component/license/tool where I can intergrate with my wireless setup and can generate ramdom username & password for our guest internet users. I came to know ISE can be used for that but still do not have much idea over it.

thanks and regards

Comment: Why do you feel the need to generate a random account every time?  That seems excessive to me for a guest network

Comment: in our organisation, we have guest users to whom we provide paid internet service, so probably there can be upto 30-50 guest users who will opt for this service from us.

Comment: You could use something like [daloradius](http://www.daloradius.com/) and have the WLC auth against it. I haven't done that specifically with a WLC so I'm not going to write it up as a answer, but I'd take a look in that direction.

Comment: I just came across some tool called AntaMedia Hotspot software, can someone tell me further about it.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score -1):

For Creating local Guest user account try below link:

https://youtu.be/UiPBI2jkaxM

try the below link to create guest account under lobby admin:

https://youtu.be/eJ4leeOaQKM

Comment: Link only answers are no good as links go bad, and this site is meant to be an archive. You include the relevant information in the answer, then link to provide proper attribution and backup.